# Is There An Active Directory Alternative

Tags: active-directory, ldap

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What Are Some Good Open Source Alternatives to Active Directory?](https://serverfault.com/questions/13419/what-are-some-good-open-source-alternatives-to-active-directory)

Is there an alternative (preferably FREE/Open Source) to Active Directory. Either managed via Windows or Linux environment.

Comment: Active Directory is a **huge** system. Which aspects of its functionality are you looking to use?

Comment: Usually, this is done with Samba (for getting auth and much more to Windows machines) and/or openldap (for the directory services functionality).  AD is very tightly integrated into Windows, so it's not going to be able to do a drop in replacement for all it's functionality.

Comment: @ErikA everything... object management and manipulation for workstation clusters in the windows environment. But I see questions like mine are unnacceptable.

Comment: @Mechaflash - there is *nothing* that replicates all of AD's functionality. Of course this begs the question - if you want all of AD's functionality, why not just use AD?

Comment: We are a non-profit group, and getting the licenses to support our infrastructure is too costly.

Comment: @Mechaflash - check out TechSoup. They have MS Server licenses there for *very* cheap, available only for registered non-profits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Samba 4 has been stated to be incorporating AD features. But Samba 4 has been in development for a while now. Like stated above, the functionality would most likely be limited.

Comment: Thanks. Just started looking into Samba 4. It's still in Alpha. However, we are a non-profit that can't afford active directory licenses so it's worth a shot.

Comment: A non-profit should be able to obtain special pricing from Microsoft, for example through TechSoup.  If your organisation isn't tech focussed, you will likely spend more money overall getting an OpenSource solution implemented than just getting Windows Server 2008 R2 at non-profit rates.

Comment: Also, if you can point out the functionality of AD that you need, I am sure we can come up with more solutions for you.

Answer (score 0):

It depends. AD provides a wide range of services.  It may be possible to find alternatives to all of them, however I don't think you'll find a single solution that replicates all of the functionality.